# Call and stop a rest service with an interval of time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to make a rest call every x interval seconds (3000 ms) to consult the status of a webservice until i have the wanted result or until 12 times (for example) or when I receive the status expected:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var i=0;
    var _onSuccess = function(response) {
        if (response.status=== 'READY' || i >= 12) {
            clearInterval(x);
            if(response.status !== 'READY') {
                $location.path('/errorView');
            }
        }
    }
    var x = setInterval(function () {
       $rest.getSomething(_onSuccess)
    }, 3000);
}
```

I have another function that calls myFunction with a timeout because if I dont receive the expected result after 32 seconds i want to cancel stop rest call and go to an error view.

```
function myFunction2() {
    myFunction();
    $timeout(function () {
        $location.path('/routeWhenStatusReady');
    }, 32000); 
}
```

Is there any way to improve this? I want to finish timeout myFunction2 if the Ready status is ok in 16 seconds for example and not to wait 32 seconds...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could set the $timeout in a variable:

`var myTimeout = $timeout`

and finish it with:

`$timeout.cancel(myTimeout);`

Answer (score 0):

Store the `$timeout` timer in a global scope which can be accessed by `myFunction`. And cancel the timer when you reach your desired result.

```
var timer=null;

function myFunction(){
var i=0;
    var _onSuccess = function(response){
        if (response.status=== 'READY' || i >= 12) {
            clearInterval(x);
            if(timer){
              $timeout.cancel(timer);
            }
            if(response.status !== 'READY'){
                $location.path('/errorView');
            }
        }
    }
var x = setInterval(function () {
            $rest.getSomething(_onSuccess)
        }, 3000);
}

function myFunction2(){
      myFunction();
      timer = $timeout(function () {
        $location.path('/routeWhenStatusReady');
      }, 32000); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

step 1 :

> assign $interval to a variable

```
 var timeHandler = $interval(() => {
                // your code
 }, 1000) };
```

step 2:

> and cancel it when ever you want by passing variable in **interval cancel function**

```
$interval.cancel(timeHandler);
```

Refrence : [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)